# CALayer - strange drawInContext bug

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, cgcontext

I'm currently having a very strange bug with regard to a CALayer subclass. This CALayer subclass is responsible for drawing a UI element, and is contained inside of a custom UIView class. When the UIView receives touch events, it changes the UIElementLayer's properties, causing the layer to be redrawn.

However, the weird problem that I'm having is that occasionally the layer will freeze up. When I say freeze up, I mean that drawInContext() does not get called until the first second of the next minute. Literally every time it freezes up, I can count on it going back to normal at the :00 component of the next minute. I have tried debugging all of my functions, and I just can't find a reason why this is happening. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

The details of that class are:

```
@interface UIElementLayer : CALayer

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat beginningValue;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat endingValue;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldReset;
@end

@implementation UIElementLayer
@dynamic beginningValue, endingValue, shouldReset;

- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer
{
    if (self = [super initWithLayer:layer])
    {
        if ([layer isKindOfClass:[UIElement class]])
        {
            UIElement *element = (UIElement *)layer;
            self.shouldReset = element.shouldReset;
            self.startingValue = element.startingValue;
            self.endingValue = element.endingValue;
        }
    }

    return self;
}

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"startingValue"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"endingValue"]
       || [key isEqualToString:@"shouldReset"])
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];

}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem (or maybe it is?) but don't call your own classes UIxxx. This is UIKit's class prefix, there could well be private API already using this very class name, or new stuff in the future.

Comment: Why are the properties declared as @dynamic? Where are the accessors defined?

Comment: So it appears that I didn't want dynamic properties after all since I wasn't doing any animations. I ended up scrapping the needsDisplayForKey function, changing the properties to @synthesized, and manually implementing accessors. I believe the issue had to do with the BOOL property shouldReset not being updated in certain situations, as well as the fact that it should only redraw the layer if the property is YES.